# AI is trying to move to my position, it makes me stuck

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

[player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwED5.jpg)
[Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnWIz.jpg)   [camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF1uN.jpg)   [enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOnVI.jpg)    [enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99cXz.jpg)

i tried to do simple AI from Brackeys Tutorial, it works, but when i get too close to the cube it "consumes" me. I cant move out of it. I dont have any character model for the player, i only have camera, and i baked the floor (whatever it means, i found this tip on comments and it helped AI to move).
Second thing is that cube starts half under the map, if i lift it up, then it wont move at all. Also i have a skeleton asset model, how do I use it to become the model for the enemy ? Also in the comments i read that it wont work for second cube, what should i change to have multiple enemies ? Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour {

    #region Singleton
    public static PlayerManager instance;
     void Awake()
    {
        instance = this; 
    }
    #endregion

    public GameObject player;
}
```

And second script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class EnemyControler : MonoBehaviour {

    public float LookRadius = 10f;
    Transform target;
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start ()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;
    }

    void Update () {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

        if (distance <= LookRadius)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(target.position);

            if (distance < agent.stoppingDistance)
            {
                FaceTarget();
            }
        }
    }
    void FaceTarget ()
    {
        Vector3 direction = (target.position = transform.position).normalized;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, LookRadius);
    }
}
```

Character Controller: mysz=mouse and klawiatura=keybord, rest of the words are height, speed value etc.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Obiekt odpowiedzialny za ruch gracza.
    public CharacterController characterControler;

    public float predkoscPoruszania = 9.0f;
    public float wysokoscSkoku = 7.0f;
    public float aktualnaWysokoscSkoku = 0f;
    public float predkoscBiegania = 7.0f;

    public float czuloscMyszki = 3.0f;
    public float myszGoraDol = 0.0f;
    public float zakresMyszyGoraDol = 90.0f;

    void Start()
    {
     characterControler = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        klawiatura();
        myszka();

    }

    private void klawiatura()
    {

        float rochPrzodTyl = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * predkoscPoruszania;

        float rochLewoPrawo = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * predkoscPoruszania;

        if (characterControler.isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            aktualnaWysokoscSkoku = wysokoscSkoku;
        }
        else if (!characterControler.isGrounded)
        {
            aktualnaWysokoscSkoku += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        Debug.Log(Physics.gravity.y);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("left shift"))
        {
            predkoscPoruszania += predkoscBiegania;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp("left shift"))
        {
            predkoscPoruszania -= predkoscBiegania;
        }
        Vector3 ruch = new Vector3(rochLewoPrawo, aktualnaWysokoscSkoku, rochPrzodTyl);
        ruch = transform.rotation * ruch;
        characterControler.Move(ruch * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void myszka()
    {
         if (!PauseMenu.GameIsPaused)
            {
            float myszLewoPrawo = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * czuloscMyszki;
            transform.Rotate(0, myszLewoPrawo, 0);

            myszGoraDol -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * czuloscMyszki;
            myszGoraDol = Mathf.Clamp(myszGoraDol, -zakresMyszyGoraDol, zakresMyszyGoraDol);
            Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(myszGoraDol, 0, 0);
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: " baked the floor (whatever it means, i found this tip on comments and it helped AI to move)", if you're using the NavMesh system it means that there is a flat 2d map which the AI can navigate via. This is much faster than to navigate in 3d space. So with a prebaked map it runs as it should.

Comment: "Second thing is that cube starts half under the map, if i lift it up" Is the cube the AI? Is the AI supposed to move close to you?

Comment: Ai is supposed to walk towards me and attack me (but i dont have any combat system at the moment, i'll add it next), i want it to work just like in skyrim, the problem is the cube "enters" the player, i dont know if its becasue i dont have a player model or just a bad script. Also i checked baked area, it is like not 2d, it detects hills and mountain i made on terrain, but the cube is still half way under the map

Answer (score 1):

> when i get too close to the cube it "consumes" me. I cant move out of it.

What behaviour are you intending for the cube to have? Follow you but not so closely? Move slower than you?

**If you wish it to stop further away** you can increase the `agent.stoppingDistance` in the inspector.

**If you wish it to move slower** you can adjust the speed on the NavMeshAgent component which it uses to move. This will be located on the cube GameObject.

> i baked the floor (whatever it means, i found this tip on comments and it helped AI to move)

**Baking** is used for various purposes, but in most if not all cases to simplify complex information to something that is more usable while also being performance friendly. In your case it sounds like you baked a Navigation Mesh, which is like a flat 2d map overlaying your static objects. This can be used by AI to navigate if you have a pathfinding system such as using NavMeshAgents. You should be able to see it if you go to Window -> Navigation and a blue area appears on your scene view, this will be your baked navigation map.

> Also i have a skeleton asset model, how do I use it to become the model for the enemy ?

**Drag it into the scene view, it then becomes a GameObject**. You can now attach components and scripts to it like the cube or other objects you work on.

> Also in the comments i read that it wont work for second cube, what should i change to have multiple enemies

In the code you set your target via a Singleton programming pattern (the 'instance' part). This means that there can ever only be one of those targets.

If your intention is to have more allowed targets then you shouldn't use a Singleton pattern but instead use a different approach to find a target, for example by checking if they entered a collider which is set up as a trigger.

Please elaborate if I misunderstood something.

And please tell more about what you are trying to achieve so I won't have to speculate :-). Remember this for future posts. Although generally speaking a decently good post as you did give a lot of information.

EDIT: Collider Trigger example

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    Debug.Log("Trigger entered"); //Just to write in console when trigger is activated.
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) //Check the tag, this can be set at the top of the inspector when you select the player, look top left in the inspector window.
    {
    //Player entered, attack him!
    //other == player in this case.
    }
}
```